# (Ruby) how to insert a pair into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a 2D array that is to have the name and slug of each school in a database, as pairs.
I want to start this array off empty and then add each school one-by-one to it.

This is what I have tried:

```
<% schoolSelect = [] %>
<% @schools.each { |x| schoolSelect += [x.name, x.slug] } %>
```

However, this adds the name and slug of a school into the array in session, instead of two-dimensional.

Comment: what is inside the @schools and what you want in output plz tell

Comment: You are still using the code snippet instead of normal code block. Please stop using it unless you have a runnable exemple to show.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It feels to me like you are going to use that array in a `select`? If that is the case there might be better solutions, since there are quite clever form builder methods.

Comment: @Marc-Andre apologies, edited above, let me know if it's correct now.

Comment: @spickermann not exactly - doing some dancing around with links and buttons in combination with select

Comment: @TusharPal there is a school name and a school slug, among other things unimportant to the Q

Comment: @keyan.r It's correct, thank you for modifying it. It take less space in your question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<<` instead of `+=`:

```
schoolSelect = []
@schools.each { |x| schoolSelect << [x.name, x.slug] }
```

Or even better use the Ruby idiom `map`:

```
schoolSelect = @schools.map { |s| [s.name, s.slug] }
```

This works, because `map` already returns an array.